# Where clause on mongoose populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

in a `Node.js` App, i use this code to fetch some data:

```
Users.find({user_enabled:true}).populate('books')...
```

but right now i have a problem. i just want users with books that are in english language.

right now i'm doing this: fetch all users and all books for them. then in a loop, i can check each book language.. this is not a good solution. i need something like Where clause in SQL. if a user don't have a book in english language, i don't need that user in the result. `Mongodb`/`mongoose` cant do this? j have to use a code after fetching all results for this?

i need something like this:

```
Users.find({user_enabled:true}).populate('books').where({'books.language':'en'})
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with match:

```
Users
  .find({ user_enabled: true })
  .populate({
    path: 'books',
    match: { 'language': 'en' },
  })
  .exec()
```

For more details check http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: this is works but has a problem. i have some users with a null value for book(those that dont have a population). imagine we have 1 million users that one of them has english book. all of them fetches from database and only one of them has populated book. i need a betted condition. is this possible that we put a condition in find section that set a condition on population section?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't know and didn't find how to do it. If you have quite a few users without books at all you can filter them in find() query like this: Users.find({ user_enabled: true, "books.0": {$exists: true} }) - this will let you to populate only users who have at least one book. And if you don't find any other solution, you would probably just filter users after exec() query to remove those who have books set to null.